# Extending Tarski's Theorem on invariant measures

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, measure-theory

Tarski's Theorem says that if $G$ acts on $X$ and $E$ is a non-$G$-paradoxical subset of $X$, then there is a finitely additive $G$-invariant measure $\mu:2^X\to[0,\infty]$ with $\mu(E)=1$.

I am wondering if the following is known?  Let $U$ be the set of all non-$G$-paradoxical subsets of $X$.  Is there a function $\nu:2^X \times U\to[0,\infty]$ such that (a) $\nu(-,A)$ is a finitely additive measure, (b) $\nu(A,A)=1$, (c) $\nu(gB,hA)=\nu(B,A)$ for all $g,h$ in $G$, and (d) $\nu(A,B)\nu(B,C)=\nu(A,C)$ whenever the left-hand-side is defined (i.e., isn't zero times infinity)?  (We could call $\nu$ a relative probability.  Cf. [this](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3080939).)

I suspect Wagon's proof of Tarski's Theorem can be extended to prove this, but I don't want to go to the trouble of going through all the details if it's in the literature.

Comment: Do you really want all $g,h\in G$ in condition (c)? In particular, taking $h=1$ and $g$ arbitrary, you'd have $\nu(gB,A)=\nu(B,A)$ and in particular, thanks to (b), $\nu(gA,A)=1$ for all $g$ and all $A$.

Comment: Yeah, I did want the stronger condition here.  A weaker one would be $\nu(gB,gA)=\nu(B,A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to answer this in the negative by providing a counter example.  Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb Z, 2^\mathbb Z)$ together with the action by $G := \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}) \times \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ defined by:

$(\gamma,\xi)(n):=
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
     \gamma(n)
 & : n \hspace{1.5ex}\mbox{even}
 \\
     \xi(n)
 & : n \hspace{1.5ex}\mbox{odd}
\end{array}\right.$

taking $\gamma$ as a permutation of the even numbers and $\xi$ as a permutation of the odd numbers.

It is not hard to see that the associated type semigroup is isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb N^2}$ (since we are forced into counting the number of evens and/or odds in a subset of $\mathbb N$).  There are precisely four idempotent (types associated to $G$-paradoxical subsets) elements of the type semigroup.  They are $\{ \varnothing, (\infty,0),(0,\infty), (\infty,\infty) \}$.

Up to a choice of unit above each of these there aren't many stationary finitely additive measures.  They are all parametrized by what they do to the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{0\}$. Any such measure is of the form $\nu(E) = c_1 \times$ (# evens in E) $+ \hspace{1ex} c_2 \times$ (# odds in E) where $c_1,c_2 \in [0,\infty)$.

Consequently, no extension satisfying (a)-(d) exists because (d) would require that for $A = \{1\}, \hspace{1ex} B = \{\mbox{evens}\} \cup \{1\}, \hspace{1ex}$ and $C = \{\mbox{odds}\} \cup \{0\}$ we have constants:

$\nu(A,B) \nu(B,C) = c_2 \times \infty = \infty \neq c_1 = \nu(A,C)$

Comments: As pointed out by the OP (thanks for the catch!) the action I orginally tried to use wasn't a group action.  In messing about with this I also ran into some difficulty actually proving that the type semigroup is isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{N}^2}$ so I threw the full automorphism group at it so I'd have easy cardinality arguments guaranteeing that fact.

Comment: I feel kind of stupid, but it seems to me that when you compose an action by 2 with an action by 3, you get an action that shifts the odds by 1 and shifts the evens by 1, and that action isn't in $G$.

Comment: Okay, I think that it is right now.  If it isn't I'll get back to it tomorrow. I just made a bunch of mistakes in a row and think I could better serve the world by sleeping at the moment.  Sorry for all the edits.

Comment: Woke up at night and thought could prove it for all Abelian $G$ that act transitively on $X$, by nonstandard analysis. Quick version for finitely generated ones: Let $A_k$ be all products of $k$ generators/inverses. Observe $|A_{k+1}-A_k|\le |A_1|$. Let $M$ be infinite. Let $\mu(A)=|{}^*A\cap A_M|$ for $A\subseteq G$. Let $g$ be a generator. Observe that $G\subset A_M$, so $\mu(gA)=\mu(A)$ if $A$ is finite. If $A$ is infinite, $||A\cap A_M|-|gA\cap A_M|| \le |A_{M+1}-A_{M-1}| \le 2|A_1|$. Let $\nu(A,B)=st(\mu(A)/\mu(B))$. Transfer from $G$ to $X$. (May be wrong. I'm sleepy!)

Comment: I missed that your current modification (unlike the one I saw last night) wasn't Abelian.

Comment: Looks like the example works.  By invariance and (b), $\nu(-,C)$ counts the evens and $\nu(-,B)$ counts the odds.  So $\nu(A,B)=1$, $\nu(B,C)=\infty$ and $\nu(A,C)=0$.  I wonder what happens if we have no paradoxical sets or if we have transitive action.

Comment: I don't follow your candidate argument for abelian groups and believe the conjecture still fails.  If we act by $\mathbb{Z}^2$ translating evens in the first component and odds in the second while you may get multiple types associated to different infinite collections of evens (or odds) the same problem arises.

Comment: Yeah, the candidate argument didn't work: I wrongfully assumed linear growth in $G$.  That's what comes of doing math in bed while also trying to fall asleep. :-)

Comment: But I do think a version of my argument works for your $\mathbb Z^2$ action. Let $L$ be a hyperfinite positive integer. Let $M=[-L,L]\cap {}^*\mathbb Z$ and $\mu(A)=|{}^*A\cap M|$ (internal cardinality) for $A\subseteq\mathbb Z$. If $A$ is finite, $\mu(\pi A)=\mu(A)=|A|$ for all $\pi\in G$. If $A$ is infinite, $|\mu(\pi A)-\mu(A)|\le |(({}^*\pi) M) \Delta M| \le 2d_\pi$, where $d_\pi$ is the distance by which $\pi$ translates and $\Delta$ is symmetric difference. I think $\nu(A,B)=st(\mu(A)/\mu(B))$ then does the job, no?